# In xsl:when, which is having executing speed? Either individual when conditions or grouped all conditions in one when?

Tags: xslt

My code involves two `choose` statements, to quickly execute, which is the right tag, where I am having nearly 50 conditions of the same format.

```
 <xsl:choose><!--Individual whens-->
        <xsl:when test="starts-with(., 'Kishan')">
            <b><xsl:apply-templates/></b>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="starts-with(., 'Gagan')">
            <b><xsl:apply-templates/></b>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="starts-with(., 'Likhith')">
            <b><xsl:apply-templates/></b>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="starts-with(., 'Kowshik')">
            <b><xsl:apply-templates/></b>
        </xsl:when>
 </xsl:choose>


 <xsl:choose><!--grouped when-->
        <xsl:when test="starts-with(., 'Kishan') or starts-with(., 'Gagan') or starts-with(., 'Likhith') or starts-with(., 'Kowshik')">  
            <b><xsl:apply-templates/></b>
        </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Please edit the title of your post. The title is a short summary of what your question is about, _not_ the question itself. Instead, add your actual question to the post.

Comment: The answer to this is that it doesn't matter. Make your code readable first and address performance issues when they actually show up. Don't try to guess about performance. You will be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in theory, both procedures should exit at the first true result - so if you want to optimize the performance, test the most common values first.